# How to "include" Thrift files from different modules?

Tags: scala, thrift, thrift-protocol, twitter-finagle

Scenario: One big project with multiple sub-projects, SBT build definition.

```
rootproject/
  api/
    src/
      main/
       thrift/
         SomeService.thrift
  core/
    src/
      main/
        thrift/
         SomeModel.thrift
```

What is the correct way to `include SomeModel.thrift` in `SomeService.thrift`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to find the answer.
Path inclusion works as expected:

`SomeService.thrift` looks like this:

```
include ../../../../SomeModels.thrift

// And then normal IDL definitions
struct Test {
    1: required SomeModels.Model model
}
```